# How to count total items in a column, if header name is provided

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry! May be I couldn't give a nice question title. I have following sample data. Obviously in case of actual data it will be different and more...

***Data Screenshot***
[image]

Suppose, I put `Pen` in `D17` cell then expected result will be `6` in `E17` cell as in table/DataArray `Pen` column has 6 items. Count should be `4` if I put `T-Shirt` in `D17` cell and so on....

Believe me, I tried combination of many formulas, search on google but no satisfied solution found. **I can achieve it by `VBA` but I am trying to solve it by using excel formulas only.**

Comment: I have tested all answers and found all useful. So, thanks to all. I have accepted `barry houdini`'s andwer as it is simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the suggested formulas here look a little like overkill to me.....try this normally entered formula

`=SUMPRODUCT((B3:K3=D17)*(B4:K13<>""))`

or this will do the same

`=SUM((B3:K3=D17)*(B4:K13<>""))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Interesting, I always thought when multiplying arrays/matricies, they had to be the same size. This is good info.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 You can multiply a 1*10 vector with a 10*10 matrix to get another 10*10 matrix then `SUMPRODUCT` just sums the single 10x10 array. SUM can be used here instead but then you need CSE

Comment: Yea, I just found out now that is possible from this post, hence why I resorted to using `MMULT` and `TRANSPOSE`.

Comment: Also, just noticed you specifically used the words "matrix" and "array" differently even though you were in both cases referring to size 10x10. Is there a difference? (or was that just a typo)

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 - I guess I was a little sloppy with my use of terminology - In Excel terms both `B3:K3=D17` and `B4:K13<>""` return arrays - I just used vector and matrix here to indicate that one of those arrays was a single column and the other a multi column array

Answer (score 2):

You can use this array formula in cell `E17`:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(MMULT((B3:K3=D17)+0,TRANSPOSE(NOT(ISBLANK(B4:K13))+0)))
```

Note since this is an array formula, you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula.

Comment: I will have a try and let you know feedback.

Comment: @harun24hr It should be working, I just typed out your data in my sheet and used this formula and it worked. Let me know if you have issues.

Answer (score 2):

This will count non-blanks provided user knows the maximum number of rows to set the Height of the `OFFSET()` function:

```
=SUM((OFFSET(B3,1,MATCH(D16,B3:J3,0)-1,10,1)<>"")*1)
```

to be executed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. The height set in this formula is `10`.

Comment: I'd probably change `10` in your formula to `ROWS(B4:B13)`. In this way, if for example a row is inserted within the counting range, using `ROWS` will dynamically update this value to `11`. This is one of the reasons I don't like using `OFFSET` or other similar volatile functions.

Comment: If you use MATCH to identify the correct column then you can use Index to get the whole column and then wrap in COUNTIF to count non-blanks, i.e. `=COUNTIF(INDEX(B4:K13,0,MATCH(D17,B3:K3,0)),"<>")`

Comment: Thank you, both of the suggestion are correct! If had been the user of this sheet I would have placed the input range (Pen in D17) above this table so that i don't have to worry about height.